# need help to do a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL, please help me to do a mysql query.

I have a Database Table with below structure:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
-- id    Staffid   branchid   staffname  staffpassword --
--                                                     --
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I need a php/mysql query to findout top five branchid which have most staff. I don't know how to prepare a query.

Comment: You need help regarding php or sql?

Comment: Still not clear...do you have a mysql query and need to know how to use php to read it? Do you know how to use it on php and need help building a query? You don't know both? Please be specific.

Comment: @fkupper Hi, I need help building a query, because I need top 5 branch which have most staff, and not getting what type of query should I apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no PK/Unique constraint involving Staffid and branchid, follows:

```
  select branchid
    from table
group by branchid
order by count(staffid) desc 
   limit 5
```

Guess this will do.

Comment: Hi, I am getting mysql error:  

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY `branchid` LIMIT 5' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, fixing the code